# d3js reusable chart components and transitions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create graphs using the reusable component approach Mike Bostock describes in [this article](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/). I am however experiencing that calling `.transition()` on a selection outside of the component doesn't cause a transition on the attributes I expected.

For example I have made this **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DjpfkjjDTBNvtrwSUCPZ?p=preview)** which demonstrates my question. In this example I use Mike's [`timeSeriesChart` function](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/time-series-chart.js) and then simply changes the width or the height. By using the transition operator on a selection of the chart I then call the `timeSeriesChart` function to see the width transform to its new value. However, the width/height changes instantly and only the axes smoothly transition to their new lengths.

If I add `.transition().duration(x)` when updating the width's inside the component the widths are updated smoothly, but I don't want to clutter the component with transition operators, and I think it should work to do it outside as well. It certainly seems to work for the axes.

What am I missing?

*To see the code go to the **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DjpfkjjDTBNvtrwSUCPZ?p=preview)***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [source of the axis component](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/svg/axis.js), you'll see that all element selectors are wrapped in `d3.transition()`. This is what makes the transition happen transparently.

I've applied this to your plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HoVTUY8LyWAdF0k6nDq9?p=preview). All you need to do is to replace

```
g.select(".area")
```

with

```
d3.transition(g.select(".area"))
```

and similarly for the line.